# How to Play Multiple Videos on Different Slides in Bootstrap Carousel on TV Browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

I'm working on a project where I have a Bootstrap carousel displaying images and videos. I've implemented a solution to run a video when the slide is active, and it works fine for the first video. However, I'm facing challenges getting subsequent videos to play on different slides.

Here's my current implementation:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel"data-bs-interval="10000" data-bs-pause="false" style="height: 100vh !important;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h1>TEST MODE : ON</h1>
    </div>

    <?php
      if ($resultimg->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $resultimg->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <?php
        $filePath = "admin/slider_images/{$row['img_name']}";
        $imageSize = getimagesize($filePath);
        
        if ($imageSize !== false) {
            // It's an image
            echo '<img src="' . $filePath . '" class="d-block w-100">';
        } else {
            // It's not an image (assumed to be a video)
            echo '<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">';
            echo '<video class="d-block w-100"><source src="' . $filePath . '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
      ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
      }
    ?>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function init() {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.muted = true;
    video.loop = true;
    video.play();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that code will select the first video it finds in the DOM. to target specific videos, you'll want to give them each a unique ID and use document.getElementById('....') instead

Comment: `<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" muted>
    <source src="n1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<video id="video2" width="320" height="240" muted>
    <source src="n2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
        var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');

        video1.play();
        video2.play();
    };
</script>`

I tried but its still not wokring

Comment: any errors in the console? remember for non-muted videos, and on mobile, there are lots of rules about being able to autoplay video - you may be falling foul of that rather than something in your code